# get content of <g> in SVG using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, plotly

I have a bar graph developed in plotly and emded in a web app using iframe.
on mouse hover there is some content showing on the graph. 
I dig down to see that the content is appending in `<g class="hoverover">`.
Is there any way I can get the content if the `<g>`is active using javascript/jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JavaScript**

```
var i = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0],
g = i.contentDocument.getElementByTagName("g")[0];

console.log(g.innerHTML);
```

**jQuery**

```
var i = $("iframe"),
$document = $(i[0].contentDocument);

console.log($document.find("g").html());
```